# items' height in a top navigation bar increasing with logo height

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to give the a-links the full height of the `div.topbar`, in order for them to look nice when hovering.

I've extracted this only feature and pasted [here][1]. Not sure if there is a better way to share it with you.

```css
div.topbar {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-align: baseline;
  -ms-flex-align: baseline;
  align-items: baseline;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

div.topbar #logo {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, yellow, black 10px);
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px purple;
}

div.topbar a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}

div.topbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: green;
}

div.topbar a a:nth-child(3) {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="topbar">

    <a href="#a" id='logo'>jS.tut</a><a href="#b">More Tuts</a><a href="#c">Home</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Where is your `ul`?

Comment: @Huangism sorry, it's the div with class topbar, just changed it a few minutes ago

Comment: So you are trying to make the anchor tags the same height of the container div topbar right?

Comment: @Huangism exactly, I don't know how to do that. height:100% didn't work, probably because the topbar has no height specified...

Comment: `align-items` is defaulted to `stretch` which makes your item 100% height but you have it set on baseline

Comment: @Huangism I supposed it aligned the content of the items, am I wrong? So the words are all baseline-aligned...

Comment: I think i know what you were struggling with, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is not being able to center the text and have the item be 100% height

You need to make your flex items also display flex and `align-items: center` on it. No need to set align items on the container because you want it to stretch. No need to set your anchors to display inline-block because 1) they are flex items because they are the children of a flex container, 2) we are setting the display to flex. flex direction is defaulted to row, no need to define

To make it easier to read, I removed the browser prefixes

```css
div.topbar {
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

div.topbar #logo {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, yellow, black 10px);
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px purple;
}

div.topbar a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 28px 15px 15px 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

div.topbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: green;
}

div.topbar a a:nth-child(3) {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="topbar">

    <a href="#a" id='logo'>jS.tut</a><a href="#b">More Tuts</a><a href="#c">Home</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: This is much better, but what I was trying was also put all the words on the same horizontal line (cause now the logo is at a different height), I guess it is not possible...; thanks a lot!

Comment: You just add padding until it is what you want, see my updated code